# Clion's Debugger is running program, but the regular console is not.

Tags: c++, c, clion

When I compile and run in Clion 2018.1.3, it builds fine but nothing happens. No errors either. The console opens up, shows the path location of the project, lets me type, but it doesn't show any of my printf statements. When I run it in the debugger, everything shows up and it works fine. It wasn't like this before. I tried back tracking and no luck. Inserting a printf statement on the first line of main doesn't print on the console either.

I tried re-writing a huge chunk of the code again on a different project. No luck. Can I get some ideas on why there is this miscommunication? This is written in c++ but was translated from c using cstdio cstdlib libraries.

Answer (score 1):

CLion captures the output of your program. That means output to standard output (use `printf` or similar) isn't line-buffered as is the default. Instead it is *fully* buffered. If you want output to happen you need to explicitly flush the standard output.

The reason it works with debugging might be (I'm speculating here) that CLion itself recognizes the newline and write the output then. Or that it modifies standard output to be unbuffered.